# One-To-Many mapping fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to get a One-To-Many relation working. I have the following mappings:

```
    public class User
{

    public User()
    {
        UserCourses = new List<UserCourse>();
    }

    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }

    public virtual IList<UserCourse> UserCourses { get; private set;}


}
    public sealed class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id, "Id");

        HasMany(x => x.UserCourses).Inverse().Cascade.All().Table("UserCourse");

        Table("[USER]");
    }
}
    public sealed class UserCourseMap : ClassMap<UserCourse>
{
    public UserCourseMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id, "Id");

        References(x => x.User, "UserID");

        Map(x => x.Role, "Role");
    }
}
```

I am getting the following exception if I try to make an instance of a User object and then tries to view the courses:

```
                var user = (from u in userRepository.Linq() // Fetch a user
                        where u.Username == username
                        select u).Single();

            var courses = user.UserCourses.Single(); // wont work
```

> {"Invalid column name 'User_id'.\r\nInvalid column name 'User_id'."}
>   could not initialize a collection: [Fringedivision.Rapp.Domain.User.UserCourses#1][SQL: SELECT usercourse0_.User_id as User4_1_, usercourse0_.Id as Id1_, usercourse0_.Id as Id1_0_, usercourse0_.Role as Role1_0_, usercourse0_.UserID as UserID1_0_ FROM [UserCourse] usercourse0_ WHERE usercourse0_.User_id=?]

I can't seem to understand what the problem is, any suggestions? The Reference mappings seems to work if I make an instance of a UserCourse object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the column to the has many

`HasMany(x => x.UserCourses).KeyColumn("UserId")` or whatever the actualy syntax is in the version of fnh you are on

Comment: This. Or, change the naming convention for foreign key naming in Fluent. The default is [table_name]_id, but that can be changed in the general case when configuring FluentNH.

Comment: Thanks Darren Kopp. It works now! See you in another life, brother